# Homestead issues (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php, homestead

My Homestead box just doesn't work even after a fresh install. I delete vagrant and homestead and started fresh. It works for like an hour then when i save my code nothing happens. Only way to have it working again is running

```
vagrant destroy && rm -rf .vagrant && vagrant up
```

Then after running this i have to import all my databases again then it works for like an hour then stop registering all my saves and changes. Sometimes when i do vagrant up from a restart it gives me

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

And all my key are generated and everything. When the whoops happens i have to run the destroy command and do the process again. Please help i tried almost everything

Things I've tried
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache

The issues doesn't seem to be with the laravel code side but something to do with homestead. And homestead is running when i check virtual box